# If Statement in Login test keeps failing?

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver

I am running a simple test in Selenium Java to test login however my if statement keeps jumping straight to the else saying it Login has passed even though I know it has failed.

```
        // if error message test fails
        if (driver.getPageSource().contains("User not found")) {
            System.out.println("Login Failed - incorrect username ");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.quit();
        } else if (driver.getPageSource().contains("Incorrect Username or Password!")) {
            System.out.println("Login Failed - incorrect username or password");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.quit();
        } else if (driver.getPageSource().contains("Account is locked")) {
            System.out.println("Login Failed - Account locked");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.quit();}
        } else {
            System.out.println("Login Passed");
            // Open Nav Bar
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/button")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            // log out
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Log out')]")).click();
            driver.quit();
        }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` marked in the code below. I'm not even sure if your code is compiling or rendering correctly but you might want to correct that.

```java
// if error message test fails
        if (driver.getPageSource().contains("User not found")) {
            System.out.println("Login Failed - incorrect username ");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.quit();
        } else if (driver.getPageSource().contains("Incorrect Username or Password!")) {
            System.out.println("Login Failed - incorrect username or password");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.quit();
        } else if (driver.getPageSource().contains("Account is locked")) {
            System.out.println("Login Failed - Account locked");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.quit();} <<<<<
                          ^^^^^^^  [[ EXTRA BRACE HERE. REMOVE THIS. ]]
        } else {
            System.out.println("Login Passed");
            // Open Nav Bar
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/button")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            // log out
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Log out')]")).click();
            driver.quit();
        }
```

Comment: Good eyes however the problem still exists. As my, if statement keeps jumping to else();